# Xamarin Salesforce SDK - The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am using **Xamarin Salesforce SDK Component v1.4.4.0**.

Salesforce login and Authentication works fine.

But When I do **SOQL Query** Http error happening

```
var results = await Client.QueryAsync("SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber, Phone, Website, Industry FROM Account");
```

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Above was the exception.Please help me out to find the issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you are able to get the RestClient properly.